# How to write power or cube of any number in django-form placeholder

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
other_quantity = forms.IntegerField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "in meter cube(m3)"}
    ),
    label="<b>#</b> Quantity of Other  Material to be Remove ",
)
```

I want to use cubic meter symbol in my placeholder. Tried using `sup` tag but it did not work.

Comment: Can you post a drawing of what you want? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [superscript three HTML entity](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/superscript-three/) in combination with Django's [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

mark_safe("in m&sup3;")
```

In your case it would be

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
...

other_quantity = forms.IntegerField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": mark_safe("in m&sup3;")}
    ),
    label="<b>#</b> Quantity of Other  Material to be Remove",
)
```